# Create a Lookup field on AccountContactRelation object

Tags: account, contact, relationships

Does anybody know why it is not available the option to create a lookup field on AccountContactRelation object?

[image]

I've tried to google it but I didn't find anything related.

Best Regards,

Saulo

Answer (score 3):

AccountContactRelationships are not what we call "First class objects" in Salesforce, they are much lighter weight "junction objects" (i.e. they are designed to use a lot less space in the database/heap etc.) but unfortunately as such, it means they don't have all the features available to other Standard and Custom objects. Until recently they couldn't have triggers on them either.

Under the hood as well, this record is a connection between an Account and a Contact, so is already quite tightly involved in two Indexed, secondary key relationships. In order to keep things simple and of high efficiency in that shared persistence layer, I wouldn't be surprised if the Salesforce engineers just said "No, no more relationships for AccountContactRelations"

Note: for similar reasons it can't be the parent of a lookup either.

Comment: It totally makes sense what you sad Simon. What looks weird is not exists any doc regarding those limitations for the object.